# HTML Buttons not working on mobile in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I made a site in HTML with Bootstrap, converted it to Wordpress, but now when I click on a button while on mobile, nothing happens.

It only has to open the link within, nothing more, nothing less.
This is the code.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg " onclick="window.location='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'">
```

I already saw a thread stating that a `float:none` property was messing with it, but there is no such property in my code (even when I inspect it).

sadly this site isn't online yet, it is still in development, so I can't provide a link.

I'm still a beginning developer, and English isn't my first language, so apologies for poor spelling and grammar.

If anyone can help me, much appreciated.

Comment: if we cannot see code or site we cannot help you ...

Comment: If you simply want to open a link, you should use an anchor tag and give it the btn and btn-large classes. Button-Tags should be used for forms or real function triggering events.

Comment: the code is right there...

<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg " onclick="window.location='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'">
                  Meer info <span class="icon icon-play3"></span></button>

Comment: The problem with that, Valentijn, is that the code right there doesn't *actually demonstrate the issue*. So if we were going *just* off that then everything looks good and should behave as intended. Clearly, that is not the case though, and this issue, as it's presented currently, cannot be reproduced and therefore no one will be able to troubleshoot it. Consider improving the question by adding a **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: I do not understand this, I'm sorry

Comment: Does the link work on desktop?

Comment: yes it works on desktop

Comment: Maybe try window.location.href or just location.href - worth a go.

Comment: As I said, you should rather use a link with button styles than a button tag: `<a class="btn btn-lg" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> Meer info <span class="icon icon-play3"></span></a>`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
In the example that you shown, the tag `<button>` is not closed.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg " onclick="window.location='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'"> 
       Test
</button>
```